# Dúvida em data no SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou montando um banco de dados para uma locadora para aprender SQL.
Meu objetivo é ter uma data de retorno do filme.
Para isso, criei a tabela com uma coluna de nome "retorno" para armazenar  quando o filme retornará à locadora, utilizando o seguinte formato:

```
create table acao 
(
act_id int not null,
nome varchar(30) not null,
genero varchar(15) not null,
diretor varchar(30) not null,
classificacao char(2) not null,
disponibilidade char(1) not null,
retorno date    
);
```

Para preencher, utilizei o seguinte comando:

```
insert into acao (act_id, nome, diretor, classificacao, disponibilidade, retorno)
values (4, "The Mask of Zorro", "Martin Campbell", 12, "A", 23/05/2016)
```

Ao fazer o select para ver se deu certo, a data é retornada como 0000-00-00. Entendo que o formato é YYYY-MM-DD, mas gostaria de saber porque ela não pega os valores que eu preenchi.

Comment: Já tentou trocar 23/05/2016 para "2016-05-23" ?

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondi a pergunta nos comentários. Só pra deixar a resposta definitiva, posto aqui.

---

> Ao fazer o select para ver se deu certo, a data é retornada como 0000-00-00. Entendo que o formato é YYYY-MM-DD, mas gostaria de saber porque ela não pega os valores que eu preenchi.

Para inserir uma data com SQL é preciso utilizar a formatação correta, como você mesmo disse: YYYY-MM-DD.

Sendo assim, para rodar corretamente seu comando, deixe ele assim:

```
insert into acao (act_id, nome, diretor, classificacao, disponibilidade, retorno)
values (4, "The Mask of Zorro", "Martin Campbell", 12, "A", "2016-05-23")
```

Comment: Perfeito, Eduardo.
Muito obrigado de verdade!

Answer (score 1):

Para inserir a data corretamente tem dois detalhes importantes, primeiro deixar ela entre aspas simple e converter a data digita pelo usuário no formato do banco.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: @MateusBinatti está usando alguma linguagem especifica?

Comment: eu utilizo o MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 0):

Para salvar data no MySQL, a mesma deve estar formatada com o padrão [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Escopo: yyyy-mm-dd

- yyyy -> O ano representado por 4 dígitos
- mm -> O mês representado por 2 dígitos
- dd -> O dia representado por 2 dígitos

Exemplo: 2016-01-22

Na query SQL, a data é tratada como string, portanto, precisa ser delimitada entre aspas.

```
insert into acao (act_id, nome, diretor, classificacao, disponibilidade, retorno)
values (4, "The Mask of Zorro", "Martin Campbell", 12, "A", '2016-05-23')
```

O MySQL também aceita a data em outros formatos. Contudo, o recomendado é manter o padrão ISO 8601.